# Android ; textview to adding a couple of filters , and finding best match

Tags: java, android, filter, set

I want to create an app which is getting a couple of text input from user then find the best match in sets.
To explain with examples

```
first = x ,y , z, t
second = a , b ,c ,d
third=  = h , i , j, k , a , b
```

if user writes a then b ; second and third to show up only.

i want to create  a -not sure about the word- database , has info or keywords about something.

```
istanbul will have some info about it. like galata tower and , süleymaniye mosque
paris has eiffel tower
what i want to do is when user write tower , list istanbul and paris and then if user writes suleymaniye , show istanbul
```

im a just new to android , so i need ideas for which method should i use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Edittext et=(Edittext)findviewByid(R.id.edittext1);
 String str=et.gettext().toString();
    Textview tx=(Textview)findviewByid(R.id.textview);
    if(str.equal("x") or str.equal("y") orstr.equal("z"))
    {
    tx.settext("first");
    }
    elseif("check your condition")
    {
    tx.settext("Second");
    }
    else("check condition")
    {
    tx.settext("third");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i understand your point. But i'm updating my question now , is will be a litle bit complex for using if-else i think.